# how do I configure my github account to my vsc

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

i cant deploy my codes using vsc to my github

tried making my first commit but its telling me to configure my username and user email to git

Comment: one of the first things to do when working with git is to configure git config. so configure. there's a cheat sheet [here](https://education.github.com/git-cheat-sheet-education.pdf) and a article [there](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository/git-config). Look at the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup). It's easy.

Answer (score 0):

On your terminal in vscode, type in the following commands:

git config --global  user.name 'Your username'

git config --global user.email 'Your email address'